# How to write a generic function for any data constructor?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have these definitions of a data in Haskell.

```
data Point a = Point a a
data Piece a = One a | Two a
```

and I want to have one function like

```
place :: Num a => Piece (Point a) -> Point a
place (Piece x) = x
```

how do I do this since haskell doesn't allow functions of that particular form.

**Solution**

The problem was my data definition (many years of empirical programming is interfering here...). I wanted my Piece data to effectively be 2 different things, a Piece and also a kind of piece, I tried to achieve this with inheritance which was just a bad approach. Separating data in the following way solved the problem.

```
data PieceKind = One | Two | ... | n
data Piece a b = Piece a PieceKind
```

This way my Piece effectively has two attributes "a" (in my case this is a position of a piece) and also PieceKind, this way I was able to write the place function without having to repeat it for every kind of piece in the following way:

```
place :: Num a => Piece (Point a) PieceKind -> Point a
place (Piece x _) = x
```

In addition I was also able to write functions for a particular kind of a Piece:

```
place :: Num a => Piece (Point a) PieceKind -> Point a
place (Piece _ One) = ...
```

and this is what I really wanted.

Comment: Is your intent to have it work like `place (One x) = x; place (Two x) = x` ?

Comment: Yes, instead of having one function for every constructor I want to have just one function for all of them.

Comment: Make your question self-contained by defining `Point`.

Comment: @Jubobs updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a record for the common fields

```
data Piece a = One { place :: a } | Two { place :: a }
-- place automatically defined
```

Or factorize the common data

```
data Piece a = Piece Bool a

place :: Piece a -> a
place (Piece _ x) = x

-- optionally:
pattern One x = Piece False x
pattern Two x = Piece True  x
```

In the general case, instead of `Bool` you have to use a custom sum type to express the rest of the factorization. E.g.

```
data T a = A Int a | B Bool a
```

becomes

```
data T a = T (Either Int Bool) a
-- optionally:
pattern A n x = T (Left n)  x
pattern B b x = T (Right b) x
```

Template Haskell could also solve this, but it is overkill, IMO.

Comment: Still not entirely what I was expecting, your suggestion is ok if you have a few constructors but what if you have 10 and they all have a shared function, then with your solution I would have to repeat `{ place :: a }` 10 times. There must be a better way.

Comment: @DovydasRupšys Not if you factor your data correctly, as suggested below.

Comment: @DovydasRupšys I don't think there's a much easier way. You could autogenerate the function you want with Template Haskell, which can generate code for you as in a macro system, but setting it up for this would require some care. If you have a very large amount of types/constructors, it could be worth it, but otherwise it requires too much effort.

Comment: I'm failing to see how the above factorization applies, I don't even see where the factorization is happening. Is the meaning of factorization the same in functional languages as it is in empirical?

Comment: Wait, nvm I think I get it.

Comment: @DovydasRupšys In FP factorization is also used for code rearrangement, but on types it usually means to convert a sum-of-products type like `Either (a,b) (a,c)` isolating the common factor as in the product-of-sum `(a, Either b c)` -- this follows roughly the same rules as arithmetics.

Comment: @chi isn't it *exactly* the same rules as arithmetic, when you consider the types algebraically? a * b + a * c = a * (b + c).

Comment: @Carl Yes, sure. Types satisfy all the ring laws except for additive inverses which do not exist. (i.e. all the semiring laws)